# Обработка записей в админке django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

В django я новичок, мне необходимо при создании записи используя админку джаного, сделать перевод этой записи и сохранять ее в той же модели. Для перевода текста я использую [Yandex api](https://tech.yandex.ru/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate-docpage/)
models.py выглядит следующим образом:

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
import requests

class Translations(models.Model):
   text_origin = RichTextField()
   lang_text_origin = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   text_translation = RichTextField()
   lang_text_translation = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

теперь мне необходимо придумать логику, что бы при заполнения поля *text_origin* и сохранения записи в поле *text_translation* записывался перевод. Поля *lang_text_origin* и *lang_text_translation* пока будут заполнятся вручную.

На python я уже написал простой скрипт для обработки текста:

```
import requests

def get_translation(text, lang):
    URL = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate'
    KEY = 'trnsl.1.1........'
    TEXT = text

    r = requests.post(URL, data={'key': KEY, 'text': TEXT, 'lang': lang})
    return eval(r.text)['text']


str = "Hello world!!!!"
print(*get_translation(str, 'ru'))
```

Но при попытки перенести это в Django возникают сложности. Можно ли в models.py написать метод который бы переводил текст? Или возможно есть другие способы? Спасибо!

Comment: Опишите свой вопрос более конкретно. В чем именно возникают сложности при переносе в Django?

В models.py вполне можно написать метод, который переводил бы текст. Его можно и в других местах написать Это уже как сами захотите сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, вам необходимо указать в моделях, что переводимый текст [может отсутствовать](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#blank) (причины для этого могут быть разные).

Модернизируем модель:

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
import requests

class Translations(models.Model):
   text_origin = RichTextField()
   lang_text_origin = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   text_translation = RichTextField(blank=True)
   lang_text_translation = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

В django есть сигналы, выполняющиеся в определенные моменты, к примеру до вызова метода save. Он называется [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#pre-save). Можно создать сигнал, который до сохранения модели будет заполнять переводом данные.

К примеру, так:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Translations)
def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.text_translation = get_translation(str, 'ru')
```

Дополнение, если вам необходимо создавать перевод только в админке, то можно переопределить метод [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) в админке. Например:

```
class MyAdminView(admin.ModelAdmin):
       def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
           obj.text_translation = get_translation(str, 'ru')
           super(MyAdminView, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: переопределил метод save_model в админке все работает, спасибо!